# How to refactor a data object to allow for a computed property on its internals

Tags: javascript, performance, validation, vue.js, vuejs2

I was trying to write some rather simple validation logic in VueJS and stumbled upon a seemingly simple issue I have a hard time finding a fitting solution for.

On my Vue component I have a data object which is a simple Form class instance.

```
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            form: new Form([
                { email: '' },
                { password: '' },
            ]),
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleSubmit () {
            // A callback in which an API request is performed using something like Axios.
            this.form.submit((data) => performApiRequest(data));
        },
}
```

This Form class has an errors property that contains the errors for the input fields in the form.
To determine if an error is present for a given field, a "hasError" method is added.

```
export default class Form {
    constructor (fields = {}) {
        this.fields = fields;
        this.errors = {};
    }

    hasError (error) { return this.errors.hasOwnProperty(error); }

    submit (action) {

        action(this.fields)
            .catch((error) => {
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
            });
    }
}
```

In the component's template, we check for errors in this way:

```
<input type="email" v-model="form.email">
<span class="error" v-if="form.hasError('email')">{{ form.errors.email }}</span>
```

This all works wonderfully, but whenever one of the input values in my form changes, the `hasError` method gets triggered for all fields.
So if we add 20 input fields, with 20 error spans, this method will get called 20 times upon typing a single character in any of the input fields.

This makes sense as hasError is not a computed property, and thus, does not have the caching advantage a computed property has.

I have a hard time understanding how to refactor this to take advantage of some form of caching, taking into account that I want the Form class to be reusable across several components.

How would one go about implementing this functionality in a reusable manner?

Comment: I don't think you would get much performance advantage from a caching mechanism (computed or otherwise) - the `v-if` directives are likely going to fire their expression on every change cycle, and what you have in the `hasError()` method is fairly lean. The problem with a cache is getting it to recognize when changes occur, so more code and complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make each field of Form be an object with a value and error key.

```
{ value: "thevalue", error: "some error" }
```

Then in your template, use

```
<input type="email" v-model="form.email.value">
<span class="error" v-if="form.email.error">{{ form.email.error }}</span>
```

This will also allow you to have per-field validations or other behaviours

```
{ 
  value: "thevalue",
  error: "some error",
  validations: [<array of validation functions>], // like minLength/maxLength,
  // built-in validations for some common types 
  // like email or isDigits or alphanumeric etc
  type: "email"
}
```

Comment: What if I now want to have a property to check if there are any errors? A hasErrors method on the Form instance would not have its result be cached. Having hasErrors as a computed property on my component seems like a responsibility issue, and isn't reusable.
I could put that computed property in a mixin, but then I have two separate requirements for something that should likely just be one (the Form class in this case).

Comment: I suppose you can have a hasErrors field and every-time a field-value and/or field-error gets updated, update hasErrors like `hasErrors = thisField.error ? true : hasErrors`